# How can access the control that we have it's id

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden Input in my web page that it contains another Input control's Id.
now how can access to the specific Input controls that it's id is in my hidden input value whit JQuery?

```
<input type="hidden" id="edBuyMeal" runat="server" value="BtnId" enableviewstate="False" />
```

---

```
function SetBuyAttr(s) {debugger
    var Attr = s.split('^');
    var btn ="'#'" +$("#" + $("#edBuyMeal").val());
    $(btn).css("color","red");
}
```

I'm beginner in Jquery.

Comment: Please, before posting, search the related technology references. In your case, have a look here: [http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Tip: This doesn't make any sense `"'#'" +$("#" + $("#edBuyMeal").val());`. Check the link posted by @ADC

Comment: Its not very clear what your function is meant to do.  Are you just setting the color red to the hidden field?  This doesnt make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET and standard javascript you would find the hidden field like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("<%:edBuyMeal.ClientID%>");
```

Your code is unclear, but it appears that you are getting the value from the hidden field, the value being the id of a button, then setting the css class of that button.

That would look like this:

```
var hidden = document.getElementById("<%:edBuyMeal.ClientID%>");
var btnId = hidden.val();
```

ASP.NET **changes the Id's of the elements**.  Anything with `runat="server"` you will need to make sure that `ClientIDMode="Static"` is set for `BtnId`.  This will allow you to [add a css class](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp) like this:

```
$(btnId).addClass("myRedClass");
```

While javascript will be faster, if you want to do it in JQuery it would look like this:

```
    var hidden = $("#<%:edBuyMeal.ClientID%>");
```

Comment: :it's for javascript,i want for jquery!

Comment: I have many controls on my web page.now i want to find which one that it's id is in "edBuyMeal.value".how can access to this control?

Comment: @Farna, I do that in `$(btnId)`

Comment: @Farna, were you able to find resolution?